# Difference between delete and dirty delete in mnesia

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I have searched on net but could not find the satisfied answer to difference between mnesia:delete and mnesia:dirty_delete.Is this related to lock? Any pointers

Answer (score 3):

[This piece of docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap4.html) will be helpful. It explains transactions in distributed mnesia and explains, that dirty functions run without them.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed related to transactions. Dirty give you the ability to bypass the transactional behaviour, but there is a risk for data integrity. Thus, you have to know what you are doing when using dirty operation.